# Rails 2.3.5 having trouble with form_for and fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am trying to add addresses to a user model via a form submit but i am having trouble. A user:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :addresses 
end
```

can add an address to his account via the accounts page, which is controlled by the accounts controller.

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
   def addresses
       @user = current_user
       @addresses = @user.addresses
       default_country = Country.find Spree::Config[:default_country_id]
       @countries = Checkout.countries.sort
       @states = default_country.states.sort
   end
 end
```

In the view "/accounts/addresses", i have a form that I am trying to submit:

```
<% form_for @user do |user_form| %>
    <% user_form.fields_for :address do |address_form| %>
            <%= address_form.text_field :firstname, :class => 'required', :value=>"" -%>
            <%= address_form.text_field :lastname, :class => 'required', :value=>"" -%>
            <%= address_form.text_field :business_name, :class => 'required', :value=>"" -%>
            <%= address_form.text_field :address1, :class => 'required', :value=>"" -%>
            <%= address_form.text_field :address2, :value=>"" %>
            <%= address_form.text_field :city, :class => 'required', :value=>"" -%>
            ...
        <%= address_form.submit %>
    <% end -%>
<% end %>
```

I am looking at the one-to-many fields_for code here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for

but the problem is i have multiple addresses but only want to submit one address at a time. What do i need to add to the user/address model and/or accounts controller so I can successfully create an address and add it to the user model when I submit that form? If there is an easier way to accomplish this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You need `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :addresses 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
end
```

And your form could be

```
<% form_for @user do |user_form| %>
    <% user_form.fields_for :addresses do |address_form| %>
            <%= address_form.text_field :firstname, :class => 'required' -%>
            <%= address_form.text_field :lastname, :class => 'required' -%>
            <%= address_form.text_field :business_name, :class => 'required' -%>
            <%= address_form.text_field :address1, :class => 'required' -%>
            <%= address_form.text_field :address2 %>
            <%= address_form.text_field :city, :class => 'required' -%>
            ...
        <%= address_form.submit %>
    <% end -%>
<% end %>
```

This would let you edit all existing addresses, if you need to add 1 to the list, you could

`@user.addresses.build` in your controller action to populate an empty one.

Comment: I'm confused how this will work. lets say the user has 2 addresses already and wants to add one to make 3, wouldn't there be 2 address sections? what should my controller action look like?

Comment: `user_form.fields_for :addresses do |address_form|` will iterate over each `Address` in the `addresses` association.  You could put he `@user.addresses.build` call anywhere you need an empty address to show up.  If you're using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, your params would be `{ 'user' => { 'addresses_attributes' => { '0' => {:firstname => 'First name' ...}, '1' => {:firstname => 'Second name' ...} } }` and you'd always be updating it via a `@user.update_attributes(params[:user])` call.  Is that what you were looking for or are you just looking to save individual addresses?

Comment: When i call `@users.addresses.build`, will this clear all the addresses I currently have stored in user to make a blank address? I want to keep all the addresses already associated with the User, and add another address to the user with this form submit. If the view I'm on is currently using the accounts controller, will the action the form is submitting to be in the accounts or users controller?  I seem to be confused where i call `@user.update_attributes(params[:user])`

I am very new to rails so any extra clarification would be extremely helpful. Thanks.

Comment: `@users.addresses.build` is a helper method on associations to build but not save a new record.  it will result in a new record without an ID and all the attributes blanked out, which would be committed on the form save (`update_attributes`).  In this case, rails will default to the users controller since it's using the `@user` to determine where to submit the form.  You can use the `:url` option to be explicit.  Your `form_for` will build up your `params[:user]` and submit it as a form.  You want to call your `update_attributes` on the `@user` wherever you'd like to commit the record(s).

Comment: OK i am almost there! I can submit the form and i get this in my params in the action: http://i.imgur.com/xuVRi.png however when i call `@user.update_attributes(params[:user])` the @user doesn't get an updated address. Heres my action:

 `def add_address

   @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])

   @user.addresses.build

   @user.update_attributes(params[:user])

   respond_to do |format|

     format.html { redirect_back_or_default 

"/accounts/addresses" }

   end

 end`

one thing i noticed was that @user doesnt have the address built. I tried adding the build line again but it didnt work.

Comment: The user won't have the address built on the add_address action because you just reloaded it from DB.  Once you do the `update_attributes` it should save the new address in the DB.  Does it not work after that?

Comment: No, it doesn't. when i move to the add-address action, i see the params[:user] hash there, with all the values (as shown in i.imgur.com/xuVRi.png). The @user has no address currently, so debug shows nothing in the @user hash for addresses. When i call `@user.update_attributes(params[:user])` nothing gets stored in the @user. I tried this with and without calling `@users.addresses.build` before the update_attributes call. Am i missing something?

Comment: It wouldn't be stored in the user, but you should have associated address records that are being created?  Can you check the addresses table?  Do you have any validations on your `Address` that may be failing?